# Error when run .jar file of Telemetry Viewer 0.6 in Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: java, ubuntu

I try to execute .jar file of telemetry viewer, and then i got this error message :

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.jarinjarloader.JarRsrcLoader.main(JarRsrcLoader.java:61)
Caused by: com.jogamp.opengl.GLException: Profile GL2 is not available on null, but: [GLProfile[GLES1/GLES1.hw], GLProfile[GLES2/GLES3.hw], GLProfile[GL2ES1/GLES1.hw], GLProfile[GL4ES3/GL4.hw], GLProfile[GL2ES2/GL4.hw], GLProfile[GL4/GL4.hw], GLProfile[GLES3/GLES3.hw], GLProfile[GL4/GL4.hw], GLProfile[GL3/GL4.hw], GLProfile[GL2GL3/GL4.hw]]
    at com.jogamp.opengl.GLProfile.get(GLProfile.java:991)
    at com.jogamp.opengl.GLProfile.get(GLProfile.java:1004)
    at OpenGLChartsRegion.<init>(OpenGLChartsRegion.java:108)
    at Main.main(Main.java:31)
    ... 5 more
```

You can check the project of Telemetry viewer on this link
https://github.com/farrellf/TelemetryViewer
http://www.farrellf.com/projects/software/2019-09-08_Telemetry_Viewer_v0.6/
Please help. Thank you.

Comment: It might be better to reach out to the developers on github, as I see you did so in https://github.com/farrellf/TelemetryViewer/issues/36.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the application is hardcoding the OpenGL profile GL2 which doesn't seem to be supported by the platform you're running, although the exception message appears to indicate it may support other profiles (ES/embedded, and higher versions of the GL/desktop, such as GL4).

Looks like this is the line of the code hardcoding it down to GL2, I wonder what happens if you upgrade to GL4 or one of the other supported profiles?
https://github.com/farrellf/TelemetryViewer/blob/master/Telemetry%20Viewer/src/OpenGLChartsRegion.java#L108

This is a summary of the differences between the OpenGL profiles, taken from the JOGL library:
http://michael-bien.com/mbien/entry/jogl_2_opengl_profiles_explained/